# How to write numerically into a char? In a correct way, that would detect overflows?

Tags: c++, c++11, char, cin, integer-overflow

COMPLETELY RESTATED THE QUESTION.

I'd like to write numerically into an integer type, not being sure whether or not it actually is a character type: `char`, `wchar_t`, `char32_t` etc.

Consider the following code:

```
template <typename T> class MyInteger
{
  T value;
public:
  MyInteger() : value{0} {}

  friend istream &operator >> (istream &in, MyInteger &i)
  {
    in >> i.value;
    return in;
  }

  friend ostream &operator << (ostream &out, const MyInteger &i)
  {
    out << i.value;
    return out;
  }
};
```

I want such class to handle all integer types correctly, including for example `int_least8_t` which is likely (if not guaranteed) to evaluate to `char`.

The above code is broken for this purpose. Let's assume that the template parameter `T` is set to `char` (for example, by letting the compiler evaluate `int_least8_t`). Giving this program an input of `25` will result in the character `5` being left in the input stream, and `value` will be assigned *the ASCII code of `2`* (which happens to be `50`). This is obviously wrong. Similarly, making this program print `value` of `50` will result in `2` being printed instead.

One obvious solution is to typecast `value` to `int` in the overloaded `>>` and `<<` operators. But then again, what if `T` is set to `int_least64_t`? Well, we could typecast `value` to `int_64least_t` instead, but what if `T` is set to `uint_least64_t`? Analogical, typecasting `value` to `uint_least64_t` would create problems if `T` is set to `int_least64_t`. Not to mention that implementations may define their own, even larger integers. In such case `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` could be helpful, but only if `T` is not set to an *even* larger, custom integer type.

Here comes with help the unary `+` operator. AFAIK it is meant to promote a character integer to a normal integer, so that for example `cout` treats it in a proper way. And yes, with operator `<<` it works neatly: `out << +i.value;`

However, doing same with operator `>>` is far more ugly. Simply writing `in >> +i.value;` creates nasty compilation errors. Actually, I'm not sure why. I have to use a dummy variable:

```
auto hlp = +i.value;
in >> hlp;
i.value = hlp;
```

This is ugly. But worse even, this might fail to check the range correctly. If `istream` is writing into an integer value, then according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/num_get/get/ it should check whether or not the written value is in range. If it's not, `failbit` is set, and the variable that was written to is given standard defined values. Therefore, no integer overflows arise. Here, however, I do not have the guarantee that `auto hlp` will be of a type of the exact size of the type of `i.value`. Continuing the `int_least8_t` example, `hlp` will be promoted to type `int` which is larger than `char`; therefore, feeding the program with the input of e.g. `900` will result in `value` being set to `-124`.

Of course, we could continue with checking the range by checking `hlp` against `numeric_limits<T>::lowest()` and `numeric_limits<T>::max()`. However, this is *only* possible if `T` is set to fundamental types. This will fail for custom integer types, since according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/ `numeric_limits` may not be set for custom types.

I agree that this is a very much made-up problem. But this is the point - just for an exercise, I'd like to be as much perfectionistic as possible.

Comment: Use a `int`, read this, and assign the value to the `char` variable.

Comment: Actually AFAIK this is what I'm doing, and I enumerated in my answer the problems with this.

Comment: To validate input you can check before assignment back to `c` if `hlp` is in the correct range. You can check range with `std:numeric_limits`

Comment: @Raxvan Assuming I know this is a char. This might be a generic type, perhaps even a custom integer type, and AFAIK the standard prohibits setting `numeric_limits` for custom types (or at least http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/ says so)

Comment: afaik there is no way to force an istream to treat a char as integer. I would do what @Raxvan said. Not sure what the downvotes are for, I think this is a legit question, although could be much more generally stated.

Comment: @Dave by the way, why is the simple solution with unary plus producing compilation errors?

Comment: @Dave There is a problem. From a perfectionistic point of view, `int` can be as small as 16bit, and `char32_t` is 32bit... So just using `int` may create problems. I think the unary + operator is safer.

Comment: `int` is guaranteed to be >= size than `char`, and `+c` is guaranteed to give you an `int`. I don't see that you mentioned char32_t anywhere, so I'm not sure why you're bringing that up.

Comment: @Dave True, my question *is* badly stated. I agree with this. I have simplified it too much. I should restate it soon.

Comment: Your workaround is terrible coding. Please code properly (read an integer int the first place)

Comment: @DieterLücking uint_least8_t. This binds to char. So I'm clean.